# Find the longest array value from given search ID

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have two arrays, one with a large set of URL paths and another with search IDs. Each of the URL paths has one unique ID in common. By the search ID we need to find the longest URL with the unique ID. Here is my code, I will explain a bit more later.

```
<?php

       function searchstring($search, $array) {

         foreach($array as $key => $value)  {

            if (stristr($value, $search))  {

    echo $value;

    }
        }
       return false;
      }
 $array = array(
 "D:\winwamp\www\info\961507\Good_Luck_Charlie",
 "D:\winwamp\www\info\961507\Good_Luck_Charlie\season_1",
 "D:\winwamp\www\info\961507\Good_Luck_Charlie\season_1\episode_3",
 "D:\winwamp\www\info\961507\Good_Luck_Charlie\season_1\episode_3\The_Curious_Case_of_Mr._Dabney",
 "D:\winwamp\www\info\961506\Good_Luck_Charl",
 "D:\winwamp\www\info\961506\Good_Luck_Charlie\season_1",
 "D:\winwamp\www\info\961506\Good_Luck_Charlie\season_1\episode_1",
 "D:\winwamp\www\info\961506\Good_Luck_Charlie\season_1\episode_1\Study_Date");

 $searchValues = array("961507","961506");

 foreach($searchValues as $searchValue) {

  $result = searchstring($searchValue, $array);
 }
?>
```

This gives the value of all matched IDs. Now if you see my array there are four sets of URL paths. What I want is that if I search with "961507" it should give:

```
 "D:\winwamp\www\info\961507\Good_Luck_Charlie\season_1\episode_3\The_Curious_Case_of_Mr._Dabney"
```

If i search with "961506", it should give:

```
"D:\winwamp\www\info\961506\Good_Luck_Charlie\season_1\episode_1\Study_Date"
```

Now what I am getting are all the arrays that matched with my searched ID. Can you please help me to find out how can I accomplish this? Because I have more than 98000 URLs to sort out.

Comment: "all the arrays" or "all the array entries"? Because I only see a single `$array`

Comment: This is a good place to use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and you can add your rules in the call back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function as

```
function searchstring($search, $array) {
    $length = 0;
    $result = "";
     foreach($array as $key => $value)  {

        if (stristr($value, $search))  {
            if($length < strlen($value)) {
                $length = strlen($value);
                $result = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

To print value use:

```
foreach($searchValues as $searchValue) {

  $result = searchstring($searchValue, $array);

  echo $result;

}
```

Or

```
$result = array();
foreach($searchValues as $searchValue) {

  $result[] = searchstring($searchValue, $array);

}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: thanks exactly what i wanted but return is not printing anything i had to echoed is that a problem?